# Django: ManyToMany Inline Admin view error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Here are the model definitions:

```
class ItemBrand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class WantedItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, related_name = "type wanted")

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Male'),
        (2, 'Female')
    )

    gender = models.IntegerField(choices = GENDER_CHOICES)    
    brands = models.ManyToManyField(ItemBrand, related_name = "wantedbrands", symmetrical = False)
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(ItemColor)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(ItemSize)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "wishlist creator")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the AdminModel code:

```
class BrandsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WantedItem.brands.through

class WantedItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'created', 'expires', 'type', 'gender', 'creator')    
    search_fields = ('name', 'description')
    list_filter = ('created', 'brands',)
    ordering = ('-created',)
    inlines = [
        BrandsInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('brands',)
```

This is pulled basically right from the Django docs, and here's the error I am getting:

'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'

I am at a total loss... any ideas? Even if I literally create a linker table and set the "through" attribute in the Model I get the same error.

Broken?

Comment: Is this "corrected" code where you have attempted to fix the problem? As I see it, WantedItem.brands refers to ItemBrand and that has no through property (none listed for reverse either)

Comment: @Christian P. - that was my initial thought about the `through` property as well, but it turns out that this is the way to replace many-to-many widgets with inlines. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade Django to the trunk.

Using inlines with many-to-many fields is **new in the django development version** ([see docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)).

Using a simplified version of your models, I get the same error as you for Django 1.1.1, but it works on the trunk (revision 11785).

---

As an aside, you don't need to specify `symmetrical = False` on your `ItemBrand` ManyToMany field. The symmetrical option is only intended for recursive relationships eg `User <-> User`.

You may want to have a look at the [documentation on related names](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward), and think about renaming them to something more logical as well. If `creator` is a `User` object, and want to get the set of wishlists they have created, the default when `related_name` is not specified is

```
creator.wishlist_set.all()
```

with your choice for `related_name` (when you add the underscore), this changes to

```
creator.wishlist_creator.all()
```

but I would recommend `related_name='wishlists'`, in which case you would use

```
creator.wishlists.all()
```

Comment: You're probably right Alasdair, about both the related names and symmetry, the only reason those are in there is because I was just experimenting with different properties to see if it would make it tick.

And it would appear that indeed this change is in Trunk, and not release. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This change is in release 1.2+

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be the cause of your error, spaces in the `related_name` attribute are invalid so I'd try removing those first.

"type wanted" => "type_wanted"

"wishlist creator" => "wishlist_creator"

Comment: I think the OP may have misunderstood what the `related_name` attribute is for. I would expect the names like `wishlist` or `wanteditems`.